# How do I clear app cache/data on Android without accessing settings?

Tags: cache, delete

I actually can't open the settings and desperately want to clear the cache of an app which is not working properly. When I open the settings app, it is forcefully closed down again and again.

How do I clear app cache/data on Android without accessing settings?

Comment: Do you have USB debugging enabled or root access? You can easily use `pm clear PACKAGE` using adb or clear the cache files using a file explorer if rooted.

Comment: Firelord, why not make this an answer.

Comment: Community bump prevention: this question was closed because the question seems to have been abandoned (OP hasn't visited the network for more than 5 years, and no answers have score above 0). If anyone can evaluate the existing answers, feel free to vote accordingly and reopen the question (or mod-flag the question requesting for reopening). For anyone else having the same issue, please post a new question and refer to this question as additional context.

Answer (score 0):

There are some apps that can do that. [CCleaner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piriform.ccleaner) is less intrusive but does not work well with some devices. You might want to try each.

Just in case you want a quick method to clear your app data, and do not want to install anything, you could try opening your "Recent apps" (you can access it by tapping one of the buttons on the bottom of your phone, and it shows a list of all the apps that are open). Then long-press the app which needs to have its data cleared, and select "App Info". This will take you directly to the settings page in which you can clear the app's data.

Answer (score 0):

Use this command with adb:

> adb shell pm trim-caches 128G

You don't need root to do this.